# How to rename certain directories if the parent has a particular name?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename

I have to do some global renaming in an Eclipse plugin project, although the fact that the code is Java and it's an Eclipse plugin is irrelevant.

Basically, the steps I need to perform are the following:

1. `find . -name "*" -type f | grep -v \.git | xargs sed -i 's/com.foo/org.bar/g`
2. for all directories (excluding `.git`) in `src/com`, rename to `src/org`
3. for all directories (excluding `.git`) in `src/org/foo`, rename to `src/org/bar`
4. for all file and directory names (excluding .git) with `com.foo` in the name, change that portion to `org.bar`.

I only have an explicit command line for the first step.

I could manage to do the other steps semi-manually, but I think it would be worthwhile to determine an automated method for doing this.  The second and third steps are equivalent, but the fourth step is different.

I want to do this with pure bash command line, but I could settle for a simple bash or perl script.

**Update**:

Actually, I need to search for more than just `src/com`.  I also need `src/main/java/com` and `src/test/java/com`.

For this, I've been experimenting with something like this:

```
find . -type d -name "com" | grep "\(/src/com\|/src/main/java/com\|/src/test/java/com\)" | xargs -n1 -i{} echo mv {} $(echo {} | sed -e 's/com/org/g')
```

This gets close, but the last `sed` is not matching, so it doesn't change it.  It results in lines like this:

```
mv ./plugins/.../src/com ./plugins/.../src/com
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1

For your first step, in your command example, you do not need the `*` because that is not filtering any file. What you do need is to filter `.git`, as this:

```
$ find . -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -print
```

That will reject (`-prune`) any directory exactly named `.git` and everything inside it.

That removes the need of `grep -v ".git"`. The sed could not be avoided, as it is editing the internals of a file, not something that find could do.

But still, we can simplify (quoting the dot inside sed):

```
$ find . -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/com\.foo/org\.bar/g' '{}' \+
```

That will accumulate filenames (similar to xargs) to the `sed` command.

But even better:

```
$ find . -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -execdir sed -i 's/com\.foo/org\.bar/g' '{}' \+
```

Which will execute one instance of sed per each directory.

## 2, and 3

Let's define a function to execute the dir rename:

```
$ renamedir (){ find "$1" -name '.git' -prune -o -type d -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//"$2"/$3}"' sh '{}' "$2" "$3" \; ; }
```

Step 2:

- for all directories (excluding .git) in src/com rename to src/org

  ```
  $ renamedir 'd/src/com' 'src/com' 'src/org'
  ```

Step 3:

- for all directories (excluding .git) in src/org/foo rename to src/org/bar

  ```
  $ renamedir 'src/org/foo' 'ogr/foo' 'org/bar'
  ```

## 4

Step 4:

- for all file and directory names (excluding .git) with "com.foo" in the name, change that portion to "org.bar".

  ```
  $ find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name "com.foo" -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//"$2"/$3}"' sh '{}' "com.foo" "org.bar" \; ; }
  ```

---

All inside a (better formatted) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: There are three echo to avoid execution of commands.
#       If after testing, you decide that it is ok to execute commands,
#       remove the echo words.

# Step 1:
### for all files (excluding .git) in . change
###     file contents from com.foo to org.bar
find . -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -execdir echo sed -i 's/com\.foo/org\.bar/g' '{}' \+

renamedir (){ find "$1" -name '.git' -prune -o -type d -exec bash -c '
                  echo \
                  mv "$1" "${1//"$2"/$3}"
              ' sh '{}' "$2" "$3" \;
        }

# Step 2:
### for all directories (excluding .git) in src/com rename to src/org
renamedir 'd/src/com' 'src/com' 'src/org'

# Step 3:
### for all directories (excluding .git) in src/org/foo rename to src/org/bar
renamedir 'src/org/foo' 'org/foo' 'org/bar'

# Step 4:
### for all file and directory names (excluding .git)
### with "com.foo" in the name, change that portion to "org.bar".
find . -name '.git' -prune -o -name "*com.foo*" -type f -exec bash -c '
    echo \
    mv "$1" "${1//"$2"/$3}"
' sh '{}' "com.foo" "org.bar" \; ; }
```

---

To test the different versions of matching, create a whole tree of files like this (remove it later with `rm -rf ./d/`):

```
$ mkdir -p d/src/{{,.git}{,one},com/{{,.git}{,two},\ .git,.git/six},org/{{,.git}{,three},bar/{,.git}{,four},foo/{,.git}{,five}}}
$ touch d/src/{111,com/{222,.git/666},org/{333,bar/444,foo/555}}  
$ touch d/src/{.git/{aaa,one/aaaaa},one/aaa111,com/.git{/bbb,two/bbb222},org/{.git{/ccc,three/ccc333},bar/.git{/ddd,four/ddd444},foo/.git{/eee,five/eee555}}}
```

Your original command (using GNU -z option to match find -print0) will match (in this directory):

```
$ find d/ -type f -print0 | grep -zZv \.git
find d/ -type f -print0 | grep -zZv \.git | xargs -0 printf '<%s>\n'
<d/src/org/333>
<d/src/org/foo/555>
<d/src/org/bar/444>
<d/src/com/222>
<d/src/111>
```

Only five files, those which have no relation to anything `.git`.

---

## In general:

There are three main ways to match `.git` in `find`: `-name`, `-regex` and `-path`.
Leaving aside `-regex` which beside being odd (uses emacs regex) is only needed for complex matches which here are not needed.

A `find d/ -path "./.git"` will match exactly that: only an inmediate `.git` directory.
Or (for the directory created) `find . -path './d/src/.git'` will match only `./d/src/.git`

A `find d/ -name ".git"` will match exactly `.git` at the last level (basename) of a tree.

Both `-name "*.git"` and `-path "*.git"` will match exactly the same.
Any string that *ends* on `.git`.

What starts to get complex is when we add two asterisks: `*.git*`
In that case, `-name` will match only at the last level of the path (the basename of the file), but due to the two asterisks `*` will also match names with prefix (note the space in `.git`), and postfix ( note many like `.gitone`):

```
$ find d -name '*.git*'
d/src/org/.gitthree
d/src/org/foo/.git
d/src/org/foo/.gitfive
d/src/org/bar/.gitfour
d/src/org/bar/.git
d/src/org/.git
d/src/com/.gittwo
d/src/com/.git
d/src/com/ .git
d/src/.git
d/src/.gitone
```

will match `.git` at any level of the path, almost as grep works. Not exactly the same as grep, as grep could have complex Regex but here the match is against a simple "pattern". Note the `d/src/com/.git/six` below:

```
$ find d -path '*.git*'
d/src/org/.gitthree
d/src/org/foo/.git
d/src/org/foo/.gitfive
d/src/org/bar/.gitfour
d/src/org/bar/.git
d/src/org/.git
d/src/com/.gittwo
d/src/com/.git
d/src/com/.git/six
d/src/com/ .git
d/src/.git
d/src/.gitone
```

Then we can modify such matches in several ways, Using (`not` or `!`) which will reject what is matched by what follows:

## Not (!)

If `find d -name '.git'` will match:

```
d/src/org/foo/.git
d/src/org/bar/.git
d/src/org/.git
d/src/com/.git
d/src/.git
```

Then `find d -not -name '.git'` (or, exactly the equivalent: `find d ! -name '.git'`) will match all the others.
Not printed here as the list is quite long.

But selecting only files is short (note the file `666`):

```
$ find d -not -name '.git' -type f
d/src/org/333
d/src/org/foo/555
d/src/org/bar/444
d/src/com/222
d/src/com/.git/666
d/src/111
```

And `-path` in `find d -not -path '*.git*' -type f` will match only five files:

```
$ find d -not -path '*.git*' -type f
d/src/org/333
d/src/org/foo/555
d/src/org/bar/444
d/src/com/222
d/src/111
```

## Prune

Or we can use `-prune` to "cut" or "remove" all directories that **previous** matches accepted:

```
$ find d \( -name '.git' -prune \) -o \( -print \)
d
d/src
d/src/org
d/src/org/three
d/src/org/333
d/src/org/.gitthree
d/src/org/foo
d/src/org/foo/five
d/src/org/foo/555
d/src/org/foo/.gitfive
d/src/org/bar
d/src/org/bar/.gitfour
d/src/org/bar/four
d/src/org/bar/444
d/src/one
d/src/com
d/src/com/.gittwo
d/src/com/222
d/src/com/two
d/src/com/ .git
d/src/111
d/src/.gitone
```

There must be something after -prune. Usually an '-o' and here also a `-print` to match everything that prune did not match. As you can see, this match much more than the five files of your command.
Changing `'.git'` to `'*.git'` will only remove `d/src/com/ .git`.
But using `'*.git*'` will work closer to grep (not exactly the same still):

```
$ find d \( -name '*.git*' -prune \) -o \( -print \)
d
d/src
d/src/org
d/src/org/three
d/src/org/333
d/src/org/foo
d/src/org/foo/five
d/src/org/foo/555
d/src/org/bar
d/src/org/bar/four
d/src/org/bar/444
d/src/one
d/src/com
d/src/com/222
d/src/com/two
d/src/111
```

This will match only the five files (not directories) of your command:

```
$ find d \( -name '*.git*' -prune \) -o \( -type f -print \)
```

As also this will match only the initial five files. Adding `-type f` hides a lot of detail:

```
$  find d \( -name '.git' -prune \) -o \( -type f -print \)
```

Usually without parenthesis (less clear):

```
$ find d -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -print
```

Warning: removing `-print` may have un-intended side-effects.

Comment: I don't understand the "! -name" syntax.  I just tested 'find . ! -name ".git" -type f' in a random repo, and the first lines it printed out were all of the files in ".git".  Also, one of your samples here has 'find . ! -name ".git"' and the other has 'find . ! -name "*.git"'.  The latter seems wrong.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Maybe the added part will help you understand. In fact, the analysis made me decide that `-prune` is the correct solution to avoid directories named just `.git` (and everything inside them). Please also read the section about `-prune`.

Answer (score 0):

### Replacing in files

Your command [isn't reliable for several reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters): it excludes all paths containing `.git` as a substring, it doesn't work with paths containing whitespace or `\'"`, it replaces input with any character between `com` and `foo`. The last problem is easily solved by adding a backslash before the dot. The problems with file names may or may not be an issue in your setup — source trees do tend to be tame. Also `-name "*"` is redundant (it always matches). Here's a safe and simpler alternative that properly omits the `.git` subtree(s).

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/com\.foo/org.bar/g' {} +
```

This still replaces e.g. `com.fooalso` by `org.baralso`, which is probably not desirable if it happens. Here's a safer construction:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/com\.foo$/org.bar/' -e 's/com\.foo\([^-_0-9A-Za-z]\)/org.bar\1/' {} +
```

### Renaming files with zsh

Load the [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function with `autoload -U zmv`, then you can use it to rename files based on [wildcard patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators). I think what you're looking for is actually

```
zmv -w '**/com/foo' '$1/org/bar'
zmv -w '**/*com.foo' '$1/${2}org.bar'
zmv '(**/)(*)com.foo([^-_0-9A-Za-z]*)' '$1${2}org.bar$3'
```